# ASP.NET MVC - How to "reverse" model binding to convert a C# model back to a query string representation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, model-binding

I have a custom javascript on the client side that I use to build up a querystring and pass over to my asp.net-mvc controller

```
   var templateQueryString = BuildTemplate();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/MyController/Save?' + templateQueryString,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
      }
    }
```

and on my controller all of the properties leverage the model binding so it comes in as a single object on the server side. NOTE: that this is a pretty complex object with arrays and arrays of sub objects:

```
public ActionResult Save(MyTemplate template)
{
}
```

the issue now is that I need to be able to convert from my C# object back to a string that represents "myTemplateQueryString" on the client side.

Is there any recommended way to take an object and do the "reverse" model binding.  They key here is that it generates a string that I could use as a query string again in the future to pass into another asp.ent-mvc controller action.

Here is an example of the querystring that I am storing locally:

```
  <input type="hidden" value="showIds=false&amp;showRisks=false&
  amp;statusIds=2&amp;statusIds=1&amp;statusIds=6&amp;statusIds=8&
  amp;statusIds=3&amp;statusIds=9&amp;showCompleted=0" 
  name="filterQueryString" id="filterQueryString">
```

Comment: What's wrong with JSON?

Comment: Can you include an example of the query string?

Comment: @TheZenCoder - I have included a simplified example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @haim770 said it would be easier if you used JSON in the request payload, and not the query string to pass your complex object to the server.

Regarding creating the query string from a model there is not a built-in method that does something like that or any recommended approach as far as i know. An obvious solution is to use `reflection` and build the query string from your properties.

Assuming your `BuildTemplate` class looks something like:

```
public class BuildTemplate
{
    public bool ShowIds { get; set; }
    public bool ShowRisks { get; set; }
    public bool ShowCompleted { get; set; }
    public int[] StatusIds { get; set; }
}
```

You can develop an extension method to convert any object to a QueryString. Here is some initial code you can start with:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string ToQueryString(this Object obj)
    {
        var keyPairs = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p =>
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Name.ToLower(), p.GetValue(obj, null)));

        var arr = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in keyPairs)
        {
            if (item.Value is IEnumerable && !(item.Value is String))
            {
                foreach (var arrayItem in (item.Value as IEnumerable))
                {
                    arr.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", item.Key, arrayItem.ToString().ToLower()));
                }
            }
            else
                arr.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value.ToString().ToLower()));
        }

        return "?" + String.Join("&", arr);
    }
}
```

Then you can easily invoke this code on any object to generate a query string:

```
var person = new BuildTemplate() { StatusIds = new []{ 1, 5, 8, 9 }, ShowRisks = true };

var queryString = person.ToQueryString();
```

This would generate a query string like:

```
"?showids=false&showrisks=true&showcompleted=false&statusids=1&statusids=5&statusids=8&statusids=9"
```

This query string should work just fine with the default model binder for the `BuildTemplate` class.

Comment: My mapping from arrays and arrays of objects from client side to server works fine with the model binder. That isn't my issue. I am trying to "reseed" a glint side from a previous info in the server.

Comment: @leora if you provide an example of the query string, and the class on the serve  i might come up with a suggestion how to recreate it ;)

Comment: I added a simplified example in the question above.

Comment: @leora thanks for the example. I have rewritten my answer to include some code you can start with ;) hopefully it will take you to the right direction!

Comment: thanks for the response.  The one issue I see is that when you do the item.Value is IEnumerable is that if any field has a string value it in it will return true (IEnumerable of characters).  Can you think of anyway to avoid that trap

Comment: @leora, thanks for spotting that. I fixed the code to exclude the string type. I think checking if a type is IEnumerable or ICollection is the simplest approach. There are other options which would make the code more complex.

Comment: thanks for the response.  This now looks like it does the trick for me

Comment: @leora, nice! i am glad i could help! :)